# Check if any radio or checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I use jQuery to determine if a checkbox or radio button is checked or not?

Here is my HTML:

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" /> Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /> Female
</form>

<span id="check1">check</span>

<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" /> I have a bike<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" /> I have a car
</form>

<span id="check2">check</span>
```

Here is some psuedo JavaScript:

```
$("#check1").click(function(){
    if(any radio is selected){
       alert("Please select one radio");
    }
})

$("#check2").click(function(){
    if(any checkbox is selected){
       alert("Please select minimum one checkbox");
    }
})
```

It is possible in jQuery?

Live example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BghzK/
Thanks for help!

Comment: why -1? please me answer

Comment: Nevermind the downvote. It is a well formed question that includes code and a fiddle. The voter probably thought you should be able to find the answer by searching StackOverflow. However, my experience is that anyone willing to take the time to post a fiddle and code has already tried searching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of the `:checked` pseudoselector in your selector expression. Combine this with `.length` to see how many have been returned. In this case we get all selected radio buttons and see if length is zero, indicating that none have been selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/BghzK/2/

```
$("#check1").click(function(){
    if($('input[type=radio]:checked').length == 0){
       alert("Please select one radio");
    }
})

$("#check2").click(function(){
    if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0){
       alert("Please select minimum one checkbox");
    }
})

​
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if( !$(':radio:checked').length){
    alert('Please select one radio');
}
```

Comment: Inside your alert you start with double quote and end with single.. it'll break

Comment: This is a good answer. Better than mine because it is more readable. http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/BghzK/3/

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use is(":checked") with the selector. Sample code below:

```
 $(function() {
           $("#check1").click(function(){
                if(!($("input[name='sex']").is(":checked"))){
                   alert("Please select one radio");
                }
             })

        $("#check2").click(function(){
             if(!($("input[name='vehicle']").is(":checked"))){
               alert("Please select minimum one checkbox");

            }
        })

        });
```

Answer (score 2):

use [`jquery Validation`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods) plugin its done automatically. For radio button you just need to make the element `required` in the form.

Answer (score 1):

```
var rdo = $('input[name="group"]:checked');
var boxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');

if(rdo.length == 0) 
    alert("Please select one radio");

if(boxes.length == 0)
    alert("Please select minimum one checkbox");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way this  simple

```
   var chkvalue =   $('input[name="sex"]:checked').val();
    if(chkvalue =="")
    {
     alert("Please checked the radio button");
     return;
    }
```